# QGIS : copy/paste with "Avoid Intersection" option

Tags: qgis, topology, copy

I need to copy and paste polygons from one layer to another but with adjustments in the pasted geometries: I need them to be cut in the same way they would have been cut by a single edit with the "Avoid Intersection" option in the project snapping options.

In Arcmap I can nearly do this with the "construct feature" tool (topology toolbar) user the target layer existing objects. But in my QGIS project I need the use a third layer to cut the pasted polygons.

Tanks